# Google visualization 12h format DataTable

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, timeline, timeline.js

I'm trying to get the googlevisualization datatable to show the time timeline in 12h format, but no luck so far.

```
google.load("visualization", "1");

google.setOnLoadCallback(new function () {

                // Specify options
                that.optionsContainer = {
                    animate: false, // Mieux pour les perfs
                    animateZoom: false, // Mieux pour les perfs
                    width: "1200px",
                    height: (75 + 25 * (maxGrouping + 1)) + "px", // <= abandonné
                    start: that.startDate,
                    end: that.endDate,
                    min: that.minDate,
                    max: that.maxDate,
                    hAxis: {
                      format: 'hh:mm a'
                    }
                };
}
```

I've also seen this response - [Change to a 24 hour format for datetime data in Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639517/change-to-a-24-hour-format-for-datetime-data-in-google-charts) - but I don't think that I'm applying it properly as I don t get any changes:

```
        this.data= new google.visualization.DataTable();
        this.data.addColumn('datetime', 'start');
        this.data.addColumn('datetime', 'end');
        this.data.addColumn('string', 'content');
        this.data.addColumn('boolean', 'editable');
        this.data.addColumn('string', 'type');
        var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a' });
        dateFormatter.format(this.data, 0);
```

I've also tried to set the `locale` to 'en-US', but it doesn't work:

```
that.optionsContainer = { locale: 'en-US' ...}
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
The `this.data` row looks like:

```
[Thu Dec 12 2019 17:30:05 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time), Thu Dec 12 2019 18:45:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time), "<div id="IP_1050" class= .. "Inactive from 5:30 PM to 6:45 PM"></div>", false, "range"]
```

and the `draw` method

```
this.timeline = new links.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline-div123'));
this.timeline.draw(this.data, this.optionsContainer);
```

Edit2:
I'm using this library - https://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/timeline/doc/#Data_Format , which does not appear to have 12h support.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Have you added rows properly? First array is time and second your value for that time?  
      data.addRows([
        [[8, 30, 45], 5],
        [[9, 0, 0], 10],
        [[10, 0, 0, 0], 12],
        [[10, 45, 0, 0], 13],
        [[11, 0, 0, 0], 15],
        [[12, 15, 45, 0], 20],
        [[13, 0, 0, 0], 22],
        [[14, 30, 0, 0], 25],
        [[15, 12, 0, 0], 30],
        [[16, 45, 0], 32],
        [[16, 59, 0], 42]
      ]);

Comment: So what you are saying is that I would have to add the am and pm variant of the hours myself and that the google.visualization.DataTable is not capable of converting them?

Comment: Please instead of  'a' try putting 'a/p'

Comment: So format would be: hh:mm A/P".M."

Comment: If that does not help look at this example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dws5ecnb/

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data? and the code that draws the chart?

Comment: @N.Djokic, unfortunately, nothing is working. Where would you add the format that you specified above?

Comment: @BogdanDaniel in  hAxis: {
                      format: 'hh:mm a/p'
                    }

Comment: @N.Djokic still does not work. It might have to do with the way the draw method of the timeline js library works. I'm looking into that now.